# nginx error message while deploying rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

It is my first time to deploy an application.
I am working on a ruby on rails app using latest version, and following that tutorial: [Deploy Ruby On Rails on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04)

everything was going right,when restarting my application using `touch my_app_name/current/tmp/restart.txt`, I get the attached nginx error

[image: nginx error]

I tried to pick the error log from nginx using:

```
sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

and got the following:

```
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2189 29260/T6 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2192 29260/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:917 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 30514, application /home/deploy/myapp/current/public (production)

[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2274 29266/T3 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:430 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2279 29266/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:500 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2281 29266/T5 Ser/Server.h:886 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2282 29266/T5 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.2313 29266/T3 Ser/Server.h:531 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.3166 29266/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:531 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:46.7083 29260/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1068 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
2017/10/08 10:02:47 [info] 30632#30632: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:47.8959 30639/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1283 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:47.9446 30642/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1083 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:47.9459 30642/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:248 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:47.9815 30642/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:830 ]: Passenger core online, PID 30642
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:48.0532 30648/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:537 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:48.0571 30648/T1 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:350 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 30648
[ N 2017-10-08 10:02:50.4687 30642/T8 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:374 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
App 30667 stdout: 
App 30737 stdout:
```

Comment: your image is of a rails error it looks like.  please include rails log of the request... log/envname.log usually. passenger logs as well..  also, include your passenger config and  ruby version for your app

Comment: Is the error consistent? Because your nginx logs shows Passenger restart fine

Comment: @dstull I do not know how to thank you brother, You got the point.It was an issue with my rails app. I finished my app in the development level and I

Comment: @dstull and I was using a theme (bootstrap theme that I bought). My app was trying to access method with nil values, since there is nothing initialized yet.

Comment: @dstull, for others to get benefit this is my rails production error log

Comment: @dstull,F, [2017-10-09T04:45:32.264748 #2133] FATAL -- : [5eb15672-c392-4c83-9388-3ae675ca088e] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: @dstull, If you can close that ticket,please do. I think I do not have privileges to do that

Comment: great!  I *think* you have to answer the Question, then accept it?  ...not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dstull I do not know how to thank you brother, You got the point.It was an issue with my rails app. I finished my app in the development level and I was using a theme (bootstrap theme that I bought). My app was trying to access method with nil values, since there is nothing initialized yet.